# Pandas multi-indexing not able to be indexed

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I have some data which has multiindex called stdDF like so:

```
                                     MeB       ReB        nB        MeD  \
gal                 cam  prof                                             
1237667323260764326 mega 1     18.722369  0.816840  0.953351  21.372606   
                         2     19.047236  0.808913  0.924270  21.399734   
                    sdss 1     20.446750  1.142743  0.169849  21.563054   
                         2     19.086531  0.958046  0.788661  21.336464   

                                    ReD  
gal                 cam  prof            
1237667323260764326 mega 1     8.113494  
                         2     8.226689  
                    sdss 1     8.499926  
                         2     8.327510  

[4 rows x 5 columns]
```

But every time I try to call a row from this dataframe, with stdDF[1237667323260764326, mega, 1], it just says `KeyError: u'no item named (1237667323260764326, mega, 1)'`

I'm trying to write to this row with another series I have but this error keeps me from doing that!

This is extremely frustrating. I don't know why this is happening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to index via tuples; and you are trying to access the columns, study the documentation, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex)

```
stdDF.loc[(1237667323260764326, mega, 1)]
```

Comment: I have read that documentation. It says I can do it as `df['bar', 'one']`

Comment: well it say ``df.ix['bar','one']``, note that it uses ``ix`` (its very similer to ``.loc``). but this is NOT the same as ``[]``. In general with a multi-index you should use a full tuple indexer, or ``.xs``. The interpretation of a list of indexers *can* be ambiguous

Comment: That example, has a COLUMN multi-index (it IS a bit confusing as it then takes the transpose to make it a multi-index on the INDEX).